# Is it possible to up a Minecraft server's tickrate from 20?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, minecraft-spigot

I'm currently running a Minecraft server and I'm curious if it's possible to configure the tickrate to be higher. Is the client-to-server tickrate locked at 20? Would I need to modify how the client sends information to do this and most importantly would it be practical? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean with "client-to-server tickrate"?

Answer (score 2):

In Vanilla the server tick rate is at most 20, unless it catches up from previously lagging.

To reduce or increase the tick speed there are various mods. Here are some examples:

[www.youtube.com/watch?v=OMYWfjgaaMM](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OMYWfjgaaMM)
https://minecraft.curseforge.com/projects/tickratechanger
https://github.com/gnembon/carpetmod